# Splitting a large data model with correctly with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am working on a project where we offer a very simple homespun CMS type backend. It allows you to edit/delete various attributes on the Page model.

There are a reasonably large amount of editable fields similar to any other CMS. We want to split these up into 3 logical section to make it easier for our customers.

We want to have a page for editing the Page content then we want a page for uploading/changing the Page image and then we want a page to upload metadata for the Page.

Currently I have a PageController and all three sections are just updating the Page model however the question is how do I best use Rails controllers to do this in a way that obvious to other Rails developers?

**Do I just have 3 methods on the Page controller, one for content, one for image and one for metadata?**

OR

**Do I create a new Controller called something like CMSController and have 3 methods on this and then just keep my PageController to do the usual RESTful heavylifting such as actually saving and creating new Pages?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I create a new Controller called something like CMSController and
>   have 3 methods on this and then just keep my PageController to do the
>   usual RESTful heavylifting such as actually saving and creating new
>   Pages?

It's a good idea to have a `CmsController` or `PublicController` for handling your `root_path` any actions you want taken care of there.

Do [read up on Member and Collection routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions); you can have as many of these under `PagesController` to achieve exactly what you want.  Just make sure those methods are private so that they are not publicly accessible — this would be a moot point though if your admin is namespaced and hardened accordingly.  You can see an example of a namespaced admin in [one of my projects](https://github.com/bsodmike/Zahl-Bar).